# TypeError: Error #1009 in As3

Tags: actionscript-3

I know that this question was posted a million times and i read all the answers but i still can' t figure out where is the problem in my game and i have this error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at habitadnew_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at habitadnew_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11()
```

I build my movie clips and my buttons again and again but i still receive this error. 
Can you please help me. I am new to flash. 
In case who someone wants to give a look at my code i uploaded my game at http://snk.to/f-ctpm6nj1.

Thank you

Frame1

```
 stop();


 tree.buttonMode=true;
 bird.buttonMode=true;
 worm.buttonMode=true;
 snail.buttonMode=true;
 caterpillar.buttonMode=true;
 fox.buttonMode=true;
 owl.buttonMode=true;
 hedgehog.buttonMode=true;


  treeA.visible=false;
  owlA.visible=false;
   hedgehogA.visible=false;
   wormA.visible=false;
   birdA.visible=false;
   snailA.visible=false;
   caterpillarA.visible=false;
   foxA.visible=false;



        function playSound(SoundName:Class):void{
        var sound = new SoundName();
        var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();
        }




        owl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

        function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        owl.alpha = 0
          owlA.visible=true;
          playSound(sosto);

           }



       tree.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler1);

       function fl_MouseClickHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        tree.alpha = 0
        treeA.visible=true;
        playSound(sosto);

         }




      snail.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler2);

       function fl_MouseClickHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        snail.alpha = 0
        snailA.visible=true;
        playSound(sosto);

          }



         bird.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler3);

         function fl_MouseClickHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        bird.alpha = 0
        birdA.visible=true;
        playSound(sosto);

          }




           worm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler4);

           function fl_MouseClickHandler4(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        worm.alpha = 0
            wormA.visible=true;
        playSound(sosto);

            }



           caterpillar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler5);

           function fl_MouseClickHandler5(event:MouseEvent):void
           {
        caterpillar.alpha = 0
        caterpillarA.visible=true;
        playSound(sosto);

            }




       hedgehog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler6);

       function fl_MouseClickHandler6(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        hedgehog.alpha = 0
            hedgehogA.visible=true;
            playSound(sosto);

         }



        fox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler7);

         function fl_MouseClickHandler7(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        fox.alpha = 0
        foxA.visible=true;
        playSound(sosto);

           }





       text_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11);

       function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
            gotoAndStop(2);
           }



        chain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_20);

         function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_20(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        gotoAndStop("sort1");
         }


       who_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_22);

       function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_22(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        gotoAndStop("wholabel");
         }



       search_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, searchbutton);

       function searchbutton(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
            trace("mouse click");
           }
```

Frame 2

```
  text1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_12);

  function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_12(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
gotoAndStop("hedgehoclabel");
  }


  text2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_13);

  function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_13(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
     gotoAndStop("owllabel");
   }



    text3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_14);

      function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_14(event:MouseEvent):void
      {
       gotoAndStop("treelabel");
       }



      text4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_15);

      function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_15(event:MouseEvent):void
      {
      gotoAndStop("caterpillarlabel");
      }




           text5_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_16);

            function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_16(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        gotoAndStop("wormlabel");
          }



         text6_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_17);

         function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_17(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        gotoAndStop("snaillabel");
          }


        text7_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_18);

         function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_18(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        gotoAndStop("birdlabel");
         }



       text8_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_19);

       function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_19(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        gotoAndStop("foxlabel");
           }




        search_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_101);

        function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_101(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        gotoAndStop(1);
          }



          text_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, textnullbutton);

          function textnullbutton(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        trace ("mouse click");
           }


         chain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_200);

         function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_200(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        gotoAndStop("sort1");
          }


         who_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_202);

        function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_202(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        gotoAndStop("wholabel");
           }
```

Frame 3

```
    birdA1.buttonMode=true;
    wormA1.buttonMode=true;
    snailA1.buttonMode=true;
    foxA1.buttonMode=true;





    search_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_421);

    function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_421(event:MouseEvent):void
     {
        gotoAndStop(1);
      }



       text_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_411);

        function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_411(event:MouseEvent):void
       {
        gotoAndStop(2);
        }


         chain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_410);

          function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_410(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        gotoAndStop("sort1");
          }



          who_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, whonullbutton);

          function whonullbutton(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        trace ("mouce click");
           }





        wormA1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Dragworm);

        function Dragworm(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
          wormA1.startDrag();
         }

       stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Dropworm);

       function Dropworm(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
          if (wormA1.x>455 &&wormA1.x<565 &&wormA1.y>430 &&wormA1.y<530) {
          wormA1.stopDrag();
     }
     else
      {
      wormA1.stopDrag();
      wormA1.x=753;
      wormA1.y=185;
      } 
        }



           snailA1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Dragsnail);

           function Dragsnail(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
          snailA1.startDrag();
           }

       stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Dropsnail);

       function Dropsnail(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
        if (snailA1.x>250 &&snailA1.x<360 &&snailA1.y>430 &&snailA1.y<530) {
        snailA1.stopDrag();
        }
        else
        {
                    snailA1.stopDrag();
                snailA1.x=755;
                snailA1.y=298;
        }
          }



         birdA1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_6);

          function fl_ClickToDrag_6(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        birdA1.startDrag();
          }


          stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_6);

          function fl_ReleaseToDrop_6(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
        if (birdA1.x>155 &&birdA1.x<260 &&birdA1.y>250 &&birdA1.y<355) {
        birdA1.stopDrag();
        }
            else
        {
                birdA1.stopDrag();
            birdA1.x=758;
            birdA1.y=405;
        }
          }


         foxA1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_7);

          function fl_ClickToDrag_7(event:MouseEvent):void
           {
        foxA1.startDrag();
           }

         stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_7);

         function fl_ReleaseToDrop_7(event:MouseEvent):void
          {
        if (foxA1.x>550 &&foxA1.x<660 &&foxA1.y>250 &&foxA1.y<350) {
        foxA1.stopDrag();
        }
        else
        {
                foxA1.stopDrag();
                foxA1.x=753;
                foxA1.y=519;
        }
             }
```

Comment: Please post code for the lines/method that causes the null object reference, thanks. Makes it easier to figure out than looking through all of the code.

Comment: I can't find `fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11()` anywhere in your code, did you type everything correctly?

Comment: I just wrote the code for frame 1. Game on frame one plays fine. I got the error when i go to game in frame number 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a noob so I cannot say exactly what the problem is. I just tested yours and my debugger says `wormA1` is null at

```
function Dropworm(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // wormA1 IS NULL
    if (wormA1.x>455 &&wormA1.x<565 &&wormA1.y>430 &&wormA1.y<530) {
        wormA1.stopDrag();
    }
    else
    {
        wormA1.stopDrag();
        wormA1.x=753;
        wormA1.y=185;
    } 
}
```

on frame #3.

Hope this could be a clue.